# What am I? Series 1.3

Tags: riddle, word

"The difficulty is not guessing the riddle. It is to **explain** the riddle" anyways, let's start.

> I kind of look like a heart shape when I look at the mirror. Better than looking at a mirror while suffering an extra stroke to look like my cube.
>
> Oh yeah that one person from ancient philosphy era, thanks for powering that theoroem but I guess if u add me one more time, I became a final theoroem to another person.
>
> But when someone, double the size of me, stands to the left of me, **WE COULD ANSWER EVERYTHING**.

I hope you know who I am, because I am really awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are...

> The number $2$.

I kind of look like a heart shape when I look at the mirror.

> The mirror image of $2$ along with it's mirror image looks like the heart shape.

Better than looking at a mirror while suffering an extra stroke to look like my cube.

> An extra pen-stroke turns $2$ into $3$, which, along with it's mirror image, forms $8$, which is cube of $2$.

Oh yeah that one person from ancient philosophy era, thanks for powering that theorem....

> Pythagoras' Theorem, where $2$ occurs as "powers", i.e., exponents.

I guess if u add me one more time, I became a final theorem to another person.

> Fermat's Last Theorem, of course. Specifically, adding $2$ to itself gives $4$, and Fermat himself proved the case $n=4$.

But when someone, double the size of me, stands to the left of me, WE COULD ANSWER EVERYTHING.

> When $4$ stands next to $2$, we get $42$, which ["Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/42_(number)#/The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)

Comment: Exactly what I thought! Well done!